# Making sections of a string into new rows based on matches in python

Tags: python

I have some data that I'm reading in from excel where people have made a numbered list within an excel cell. I want it so that each number within the cell becomes its own row, with the other columns in the row reproduced. Sample code below shows the current state, and then how the separated version should look:

```
sample_data = {'ID' : ['ABC'], 'Value': ['1) Ger, \n 2) US, \n 3) UK'}
sample_df = pd.DataFrame(sample_data)

sample_data_sep = {'ID' : ['ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC'], 'Value': ['1) Ger', '2) US', '3) UK'}
sample_df_sep = pd.DataFrame(sample_data_sep)
```

I have looked into the explode function, but it seems that is more for nested lists, where as these are just strings. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you split string using `.str.split(', \n ')` then you get nested list and then you can use `explode()`

```
import pandas as pd
sample_data = {'ID' : ['ABC'], 'Value': ['1) Ger, \n 2) US, \n 3) UK']}
sample_df = pd.DataFrame(sample_data)

sample_df['Value'] = sample_df['Value'].str.split(', \n ')
sample_df = sample_df.explode('Value').reset_index(drop=True)

print('--- sample_df ---')
print(sample_df)

sample_data_sep = {'ID' : ['ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC'], 'Value': ['1) Ger', '2) US', '3) UK']}
sample_df_sep = pd.DataFrame(sample_data_sep)

print('--- sample_df_sep ---')
print(sample_df_sep)

print('--- compare ---')
print(sample_df == sample_df_sep)
```

Result:

```
--- sample_df ---
    ID   Value
0  ABC  1) Ger
1  ABC   2) US
2  ABC   3) UK
--- sample_df_sep ---
    ID   Value
0  ABC  1) Ger
1  ABC   2) US
2  ABC   3) UK
--- compare ---
     ID  Value
0  True   True
1  True   True
2  True   True
```